# ncurses error iostream.h not found in Yocto SDK do_populate

Tags: linux, sdk, yocto, bitbake

I am new to both Linux and the Yocto project.
I am currently trying to build a custom image for the minnow board.
I have managed to create the image for the board using the bitbake

However, when I execute bitbake  -c do_populate_sdk, I run into compilation issues in ncurses:

```
../../../git/c++/cursespad.cc -o ../obj_s/cursespad.o
| In file included from ../../../git/c++/cursesw.h:40,
|                  from ../../../git/c++/cursesp.h:39,
|                  from ../../../git/c++/cursesm.h:39,
|                  from ../../../git/c++/cursesm.cc:35:
| ../c++/etip.h:341:15: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
 341 | #     include <iostream.h>
```

Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated considering that I am a novice.
I don't understand why I should run into compilation errors in the sdk creation, after the complete image was built successfully

I am using poky-zeus-22.0.2. It contains ncurses version 6.1+20190803-r0

Comment: `<iostream.h>` isn't a standard C++ header file. Is this 20+ year old code? You saw it in the pre-standard days of the 80's and 90's.

Comment: I thought the same. But the code is downloaded by the Yocto Project during the build. So I would assume that it takes the current version of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is what is described in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70129

The issue is with the -I and -isystem having the same path referred

The problem (and another related issue of stdlib.h not found) were resolved after I changed the following in bitbake.conf:

BUILDSDK_CPPFLAGS = "-isystem${STAGING_INCDIR}"
to
BUILDSDK_CPPFLAGS = ""